# Replace multiple objects in list using where statement

Tags: c#

I'm using a list adding items from a class.
I need to replace all items in same row using where statement. Example

```
 public class Foo
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string SubName { get; set; }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Foo> mItems = new List<Foo>();
        mItems.Add(new Foo { name = "Name", SubName = "Subname" });
        mItems.Add(new Foo { name = "Name2", SubName = "Subname2" });
        mItems.Add(new Foo { name = "Name3", SubName = "Subname3" });
        if (mItems.Any(x => x.name == "Name3"))
        { 
            //where name is Name3 replace Name3 with Name4 and SubName3 with Subname4
        }
    }
```

I need to replace where name is Name3 the both of values. Name3 and subname3. I tried to use replace but it doesn't show it in suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
mItems.Where(x => x.name == "Name3" && x.SubName == "SubName3").ToList().ForEach(x => {
    x.name = "Name4";
    x.SubName = "SubName4";
});
```

Comment: I would avoid that unnecessary `.ToList()`

Comment: Just do a normal foreach and you save one iteration of the collection.

Comment: @Magnus OP wanted to use `Where` though.